# Spectroscopy of Stars

Tags: astronomy, stars

Stars are dense balls of gases that have emission and absorption spectrum due to their thin outside layers. But why do stars have such different spectra even though they have essentially the same chemical composition?

Comment: if we think of stars as blackbodies, they have different emission spectra because of different temperatures.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of optical depth? And that the optical depth is a wavelength dependent quantity? Then I can formulate an answer. But I don't have time for a full course in radiative transfer..

Answer (score 2):

Stars do not all have exactly the same chemical composition, which means they will not all have exactly the same emission and absorption spectra. In addition, stars do not all have the same temperature, which means that not all the elements present at their visible surfaces will exhibit the same degree of ionization. Finally, not all stars are moving relative to us with exactly the same velocity, which means that they will not all exhibit exactly the same degree of redshift in their spectra.